# I want to display PDF inside div, object or iframe BUT restrict user from downloading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have multiple pdfs. I want to display them on my page but I don't want the user to download them. I tried using google docs but the user can open the PDFs externally and was able to download them. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try something like http://www.turnjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser can display the PDF file, the user can download it... or grab it from the cache... or find the direct URL from the HTML source... etc.

If your concern is the PDF getting out of your control and unauthorized users getting access to it, you're better off using a PDF DRM solution. There are various solutions at different price points.